# How to generate 2-yaxis graphs on a panel data per id?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataset, `df` that looks like this:

| Date | Code | City | State | Quantity x | Quantity y | Population | Cases | Deaths |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01 | 10001 | Los Angeles | CA |  | 445 |  | 0 | 0 |
| 2019-01 | 10002 | Sacramento | CA | 4450 | 556 |  | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-03 | 12223 | Houston | TX | 440 | 4440 | 35000000 | 23 | 11 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-07 | 10002 | Sacramento | CA | 3220 | NA | 5444000 | 211 | 22 |

My start and end date are the same for all cities. I have over 4000 different cities, and would like to plot a 2-yaxis graph for each city, using something similar to the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,9))

color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
ax1.set_ylabel('Quantity X', color=color)
ax1.plot(df['Quantity x'], color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
color2 = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('Deaths', color=color2)
ax2.plot(df['Deaths'], color=color2)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color2)
plt.show()
```

I would like to create a loop so that the code above runs for every `Code` that is related to a `City`, with quantity x and deaths, and it saves each graph made into a folder. How can I create a loop that does that, and stops every different `Code`?

Observations: Some values on `df['Quantity x]` and `df[Population]` are left blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are looking for a [filtering functionality](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/filter-rows-pandas):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


def plot_quantity_and_death(df):
    # your code
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 9))

    color = 'tab:red'
    ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Quantity X', color=color)
    ax1.plot(df['Quantity x'], color=color)
    ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    color2 = 'tab:blue'
    ax2.set_ylabel('Deaths', color=color2)
    ax2.plot(df['Deaths'], color=color2)
    ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color2)

    # save & close addon
    plt.savefig(f"Code_{str(df['Code'].iloc[0])}.png")
    plt.close()


df = pd.DataFrame()  # this needs to be replaced by your dataset

# get unique city codes, loop over them, filter data and plot it
unique_codes = pd.unique(df['Code'])
for code in unique_codes:
    filtered_df = df[df['Code'] == code]
    plot_quantity_and_death(filtered_df)
```

Comment: The code for graphing works fine, but I am having problems with the `for` loop. My `unique_codes` returns an array of values (i.e. city codes), but the `filtered_df` gives me an empty set. I believe it is because of the `df=pd.DataFrame()`. It is not filling any data inside.

Comment: Yes, you need to delete that line and replace it by your own complete dataset